# Visual Basic 6 Array as Argument

Tags: arrays, vb6, parameter-passing

This might sound like a stupid question, but I am about to pull hear out.

I have a Sub whereby I want to parse an array and assign it to a Class Module "Object".

How do I go about doing this.

What I do have that isn't working is:

```
Private matrix(9,9) As Integer
'The Setter Sub
Public Sub SetMatrixArray(arrValToSet() as Integer)
    matrix = arrValToSet
End Sub


'In the caller module / class module I have the following code to parse the array.

Dim theArray(9,9) As Integer
Dim customObj as CustomObject
customObj.SetMatrixArray(theArray)
```

I get the following error message:

**Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected.**

Comment: Dabblernl's answer should work. And if you have more issues, [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/passingandreturningarrays.htm) seems to be quite a good resource for arrays (it's about VBA, but that's close enough to be helpful).

Comment: @ho1 I don't disagree, but his syntax for calling SetMatrixArray is incorrect. I'm looking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcx04ck5(VS.85).aspx). Am I wrong?

Comment: @Jay: No, I think you're completely correct. I'm too used to VB.Net so I didn't even notice those extra parentheses until now. I think a combination of yours and Dabblernl's answers are needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
 'In the caller module / class module I have the following code to parse the array.'
    Dim theArray(9,9) As Integer 
    Dim customObj as CustomObject 
    customObj.SetMatrixArray theArray
```

'The Class'

```
Private matrix() As Integer 
       'The Setter Sub '
       Public Sub SetMatrixArray(arrValToSet() as Integer)
       matrix = arrValToSet
    End Sub
```

So remove the dimensioning of the matrix array in your class. You can always implement errorchecking if the dimensions must be exactly 9.

EDIT: I removed the parens around the procedure calling without thinking while testing, it may influence the answer.

Comment: Yes, this is called "declaring a dynamic array."

Comment: VB doesn't allow you to re-assign an array where you already gave it a size. The above statement does not work.

Comment: Let me rephrase. It does work if the theArray() is not assigned a value of theArray(9,9). I modified the answer. Good job. Learned something new today!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to pass the array as a variant for multidimensional arrays

```
Public Sub SetMatrixArray(arrValToSet as Variant)
    matrix = arrValToSet
End Sub
```

Check out [this](http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6/vb6-arrays-variants.html) article.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `customObj.SetMatrixArray()` try either:

Dropping the parens around the procedure parameter:

```
customObj.SetMatrixArray theArray
```

-- or --

Prefacing your call with `Call`:

```
Call customObj.SetMatrixArray(theArray)
```

Comment: +1 You can run into odd cases in VB6 where adding additional parentheses turns your argument into an expression